# How can I create a json with the opportunity products with a specific format?

Tags: integration, json

I have a specific format of the Json that I save with opportunity and account values, as in the example below, but in the LINEAS section would depend on the number of products that have the opportunity, how could I do that?

```
req.setBody(
            ' "Negociación":'+'{'+
                '"PorcentajeAumentoAnual": "'             + SelOportunity.PAA__c                                +'",'   +  
                '"PorcentajeAumentoAnual": "'             + SelOportunity.Porcentaje_Aumento_Anual_Piso__c      +'",'   +            
                '"TipoNegociacion": "'                    + SelOportunity.Tipo_de_Renta__c                      +'",'   +
            ' "Lineas":'+'['+
            '{'+
                /*'"RecordIdLinea": "'                    + SelProduct.Id                      +'",'   +
                '"Categoria": "'                          + SelProduct.Articulo__c             +'",'   +
                '"Cantidad": "'                           + SelProduct.Quantity                +'",'   +
                '"CAM": "'                                + SelProduct.Total_CAM__c            +'",'   +            
                '"PrecioUnitarioLocal": "'                + SelProduct.Prorrateo__c            +'"'    +
                '"PrecioTotalLinea": "'                   + SelProduct.Prorrateo__c            +'",'   +       
                '"IDLocal": "'                            + SelProduct.ProductCode             +'",'   +*/   
            '}' +
            '],
)
```

With the following query I obtain the products related to the opportunity with the data that it would occupy, but that data would be assigned to the values ​​of the LINEAS segment of the Json

```
Opportunity op = [SELECT id, (SELECT Id,Articulo__c,Quantity,Total_CAM__c,Prorrateo__c,ProductCode FROM opportunitylineitems)FROM opportunity WHERE Id =: OpportunityId];
```

How could you make the line part dynamic depending on the number of products of the opportunity?

Saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [JSONGenerator](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm) class and as part of the methods in this class, use `writeStartArray` and `writeEndArray` to build the array of opp line items related to an opportunity.

Here's a sample code to get you started:

```
Opportunity op = [SELECT id, Name,(SELECT Id,Name,quantity FROM opportunitylineitems)
FROM opportunity WHERE Id=: OpportunityId]; //replace relevant fields here

JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeFieldName('Negociación');
gen.writeStartObject();
gen.writeStringField('PorcentajeAumentoAnual', op.Name);//replace field
gen.writeStringField('TipoNegociacion', op.Name); //replace field 
//complete other fields from opportunity 

gen.writeFieldName('Lineas');
    gen.writeStartArray();
        for (integer i = 0; i < op.opportunitylineitems.size(); i++){
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField('Categoria', op.opportunitylineitems[i].Name); //replace field 
            gen.writeStringField('Cantidad', op.opportunitylineitems[i].Name); //replace field
            //complete other fields from opportunitylineitems 
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    gen.writeEndArray();
gen.writeEndObject();

system.debug(gen.getAsString() );
```

Sample JSON result:

```
{
    "Negociación": {
        "PorcentajeAumentoAnual": "value here",
        "TipoNegociacion": "value here",
        "Lineas": [
            {
                "Categoria": "value here",
                "Cantidad": "value here"
            },
            {
                "Categoria": "value here",
                "Cantidad": "value here"
            },
            {
                "Categoria": "value here",
                "Cantidad": "value here"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Shamina!
It really has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to user a wrapper inner class for both, Negociacion and Lineas. Then for every record in the query I would create one new Linea() and, at the end, I will JSON.serialize() the main wrapper object. It should be "easy", does it make sense for you?

Comment: Hello, the truth is that no, it is the first time that I do this and the only thing that stops me is generating the line segment, depending on the number of products.
I occupied JSON.serialize () and it does show me the products of the opportunity, but how could I occupy them so that they are the above format? that is, the first column are fields from a web service.